# Is it safe to use pt-online-schema-change in a multimaster environment?

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-tools, percona-toolkit

I have 2 MySQL servers with row-based replication between them. Both of them are masters and slaves for each other (active-active master-master setup).

If I understand it correctly pt-osc creates triggers to catch any changes while running. But from what I know triggers are not fired in a row-based replication environment. So I guess pt-osc is not able to catch changes made on the second master during the change, is it?

EDIT: While doing some tests and I saw that pt-osc was creating triggers on both masters which would cover changes from both sides. Still I'm quite unsure if I can safely do online changes in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is more complex.  (Caveat:  This is not a definitive Answer to the Question, just more insight.)

- Generally (probably in this case), the triggers should be only on the one machine.
- RBR replicates the *effect* of inserts/etc, not the actual statements.  That is what is needed on the Slave (aka other Master).
- Are you 'writing' to both Masters?  If so, that is a recipe for extra problems; I recommend you stop writing to the other Master while running pt-osc.

Also look into gh-ost, which uses the binlog in tricky ways.  (Obviously, you have the binlog turned on.)

Comment: Yes, I'm writing to both Masters but I would have to wait for a maintenance window to stop writing to one of them. Thank you for pointing out gh-ost.

Comment: Sadly, [gh-ost doesn't support active-active master-master setup](https://github.com/github/gh-ost/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet.md#master-master).

Comment: @Mrskman - Why do you need to wait for a maintenance window?  Pretend one of your Masters has failed.  _You need to test that anyway!_